# SQLSTATE[hy000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, database

[image]

error when command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php version : 7.3.14

magento : 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

you have few issues with mysql,
1 - mysql is not running / crashed
2 - socket / address path is wrong / missing

please check your configuration file `env.php` and also mysq is running and listening on localhost, for example.

Answer (score -1):

In your

> magento_root/app/etc/env.php

find  if`'host' => '127.0.0.1'` change it to `'host' => 'localhost'`

OR

find  if`'host' => 'localhost'` change it to `'host' => '127.0.0.1'`